# Text reversed on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, cross-browser

There is a email field where in if we access the site using chrome/IE/Firefox browser it works as expected, But if I access it using IPhone Safari browser the email field reverse the text I entered.

Example image here-

[image: What ever I type in to Email field reverses automatically]

The code for the field Email is

```html
<input
  id="emal"
  required
  type="text"
  maxlength="40"
  onclick="this.focus();"
  onfocus="if(this.value == this.dflt) { this.value='' }; this.onchange();"
  onblur="if(this.value.length < 1) { this.value = this.dflt };" 
  onchange="this.ffoc = true; validate_email();"    
  onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();" 
  onkeypress="this.onchange();">
```

Validation part of code -

```js
function validate_email() {
  if (document.loaded) {
    $form[0].$emal.value = "";
    $form[0].$emal.valid = null;
    updateField($form[1].$emal, $form[1].$emal.value.replace(/\s/ig, ""));
    if (isValidEmail($form[1].$emal.value) && $form[1].$emal.value != $form[
        1].$emal.dflt) {
      $form[0].$emal.value = $form[1].$emal.value;
      $form[0].$emal.valid = true;
      $form[1].$emal.setAttribute("valid", "true");
    } else {
      $form[1].$emal.setAttribute("valid", ($form[1].$emal.clik) ? ($form[
        1].$emal.required) ? "false" : "warn" : "");
      $form[0].$emal.valid = ($form[1].$emal.clik && !$form[1].$emal
        .required) ? true : null;
    }
    $form[1].$emal.$wbox.style.display = ((/false|warn/i).test($form[1]
      .$emal.getAttribute("valid"))) ? "block" : "none";
    refresh();
  }
}

function isValidEmail(str) {
  var val = false;
  if (str != null) {
    var ddStr =
      "aero%asia%biz%cat%com%coop%edu%gov%info%int%jobs%mil%mobi%museum%name%net%org%pro%tel%travel%ac%ad%ae%af%ag%cf%cg%ai%al%am%an%ao%aq%ar%as%at%au%aw%ax%az%ba%bb%bd%be%bf%bg%bh%bi%bj%bm%bn%bo%br%bs%bt%bv%bw%by%bz%ca%cc%cd%ch%ci%ck%cl%cm%cn%co%cr%cs%cu%cv%cx%cy%cz%dd%de%dj%dk%dm%do%dz%ec%ee%eg%eh%er%es%et%eu%fi%fj%fk%fm%fo%fr%ga%gb%gd%ge%gf%gg%gh%gi%gl%gm%gn%gp%gq%gr%gs%gt%gu%gw%gy%hk%hm%hn%hr%ht%hu%id%ie%il%im%in%io%iq%ir%is%it%je%jm%jo%jp%ke%kg%kh%ki%km%kn%kp%kr%kw%ky%kz%la%lb%lc%li%lk%lr%ls%lt%lu%lv%ly%ma%mc%md%me%mg%mh%mk%ml%mm%mn%mo%mp%mq%mr%ms%mt%mu%mv%mw%mx%my%mz%na%nc%ne%nf%ng%ni%nl%no%np%nr%nu%nz%om%pa%pe%pf%pg%ph%pk%pl%pm%pn%pr%ps%pt%pw%py%qa%re%ro%rs%ru%tw%tz%ua%ug%uk%us%uy%uz%va%vc%ve%vg%vi%vn%vu%wf%ws%ye%yt%yu%za%zm%zw",
      ckStr = (ddStr).split("%");
    if (str.length > 5 && (
        /^\w+([\.\-\'\+]?\w+)*@\w+([\.\-]?\w+)*(\.\w+)+$/i).test(str)) {
      for (var i = 0; i < ckStr.length; i++) {
        if (str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(".") + 1) == ckStr[i]) {
          val = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return val
}
```

I really appreciate helping me sorting this or providing any references.

Comment: Does it only do this when you submit/validate the form?  Screenshot + code imply this, but the question doesn't mention that it's caused by validation.   What does it do when the page is loaded?

Comment: Thanks for reply @freedomn-m. I am validating onkeypress and oninput. so,everytime it checks for validation on entering each word. There is nothing it does when page loads.